# Python coding exercise

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function named orderInt passed three integers and returns true if the three int are in ascending order, otherwise false. Here's my code so far:

```
def orderInt(a, b, c):
     print "Enter 3 integers: "
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
```

How do I compare the variables?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - specifically item 3 of the **Some questions are still off-topic** list.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your indentation is wrong.

```
def orderInt():
    print "Enter 3 integers: "
    a = input()
    b = input()
    c = input()
    if a<b<c:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print orderInt()
```

Second, your function is taking three arguments and also taking inputs. The arguments passed will be overwritten by your `input`s.

```
def orderInt():
    print "Enter 3 integers: "
    if a<b<c:
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = input()
b = input()
c = input()

print orderInt(a,b,c)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually the `print "Enter 3 integers: "` should be outside the function just above the prompts

Comment: @GeorgeBou, I saw that and I gave the second solution.